# Python Turtle Graphics in GitHub Codespace

Tags: python, tkinter, python-turtle, github-codespaces

Is it possible to run Python Turtle Graphics from Github Codespace? I tried and got

```
File "/usr/local/python/3.10.13/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Comment: Codespaces doesn't have any graphics implementation, so turtle doesn't have a "screen" to draw on. You could probably run it in headless mode and save the result to an image file.